# Playing An Item Card

Tags: hyrule-warriors

Hyrule Warriors Wii U edition Adventure Mode.  I have the card (the harp) that I need to use to display the hidden enemies, but what button on my gamepad do I press to actually use the card and select the square?

I have tried pressing all the buttons, and holding one at a time for a few seconds, but nothing works.  I even tried using the RL & ZL but nothing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the X button.

The UI tells you to use the X button to use one of your cards, but it's most likely that you're pressing A first to zoom-in to the battle square. When you're zoomed-in, your only options are to Zoom-out, Upgrade, or Start the battle. Yet, before selecting the stage is when X (*to use item*) will activate.

Here's some screenshots (from the 3DS version) but I have the WiiU version as well to confirm:

[image: Map Screen - Zoomed out]
Adventure map screen, zoomed-out showing the available battles. X is displayed as an option on this screen to "search" the square. (use item)

[image: Battle Screen - Zoomed-in]
Pressing A zooms in to display the battle selected, but won't let you press X to search. You'll need to press B to return to the previous view.

Comment: That was exactly my issue.  I go ahead and hit A to zoom in so I can see the square more clearly.  Even on my 50 inch tv it is difficult for me to see what medal, etc I have on that square.  So pressing A zooms in and makes it more clear for me.  Thank you!